# response from POST request NULL angular/php

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a relatively simple POST request in angular...

```
var data = $.param({
            clientID: '329272'
        });

var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }
    $http.post('./server.php', data, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            console.log("nope");
        });
```

And my php code that receives the data is the following...

```
$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($postdata);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($request);
```

All I am doing is sending data, then sending it back in the response to check if it worked.

The connection is made, and console prints out a status of `200`, but when I `console.log(data)`, I get a value of `null`. Why am I not able to receive the data?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($postdata)` to see what got received on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.param()` does not encode into json so `json_decode($postdata)` parse on the server will fail.

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/
>
> Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain object, or a jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request.

You can use `JSON.stringify` to serialize javascript objects into JSON.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify